# Need help to change postgresql port on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, postgresql

I just installed the postgresql (as it says on postgresql), server is running like  charm, no problem at all.
I just tried(want) to change the default port (5432) to (9898).
First I just tried to do it by postgresql.conf file under `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf`.
I just remove the comment for `port` related line, and change it as `port=9898`, but there is a comment saying overriding port here doesn't change anything for RHEL and deriven guys, it also says try to override the port config by service config file`(cannot find it, where is it?)`.
I also change the `postmaster.opts` too (doesn't work the same).
Finally! how may I change the Postgresql 9.2.7 port number on CentOS 7?

Comment: Looks like it is in /etc/sysconfig/pgsql. See http://serverfault.com/questions/369987/cannot-change-postgresql-port. Generally poking around in /etc/init.d/... scripts yields a lot of info too.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found it, the service file is `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service`, I just change the following line.

```
Environment=PGPORT=9898
```

stop the service as

```
service postgresql stop
```

then reload the daemon services using this

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Finally start the postgresql using

```
service postgresql start
```

Now it's working like charm :D

Answer (score 4):

Login to psql. Try

```
show config_file ;
```

That is the file you should change. Did you restart the server after changing the port?
You can also try the file under /etc/rc.d/init.d for PostgreSQL if it is running as a service.

Answer (score 1):

From /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service

```
# It's not recommended to modify this file in-place, because it will be
# overwritten during package upgrades.  If you want to customize, the
# best way is to create a file "/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service",
# containing
#       .include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
#       ...make your changes here...
# For more info about custom unit files, see
# http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_customize_a_unit_file.2F_add_a_custom_unit_file.3F

# For example, if you want to change the server's port number to 5433,
# create a file named "/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service" containing:
#       .include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
#       [Service]
#       Environment=PGPORT=5433
# This will override the setting appearing below.
```

I think it is better to follow the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Amazon EC2 instance with Amazon Linux AMI release ( A kind of CentOS it seems). I needed to change PGPORT variable in /etc/init.d/postgresql file and restart the postgresql service using 'service postgresql restart'. And it works!!

```
PGPORT=some_new_port # /etc/init.d/postgresql
```